# SQL Server 2012: Select Query on 400M static table data

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

We are expecting data from another vendor to be loaded into a table into an existing application database on SQL Server 2012. The table structure will look like the below and there are 400 million rows expected in the table. The data load won't come in until after 3 more weeks but there's a concern in terms of performance of querying the table.

The SQL Server has 64GB RAM.

Only SELECT query is expected on this table. Data is static and not expected to change and there will be no WRITES to the table. The SELECT query is always expected to return 1 matching row. Below is what the SELECT query will look like:

```
Select "Data Column 9" 
  from Table
 where "Data Column 1" = AB
   and "Data Column 2" = CD
   and "Data Column 3" = EF
   and "Data Column 4" = A
   and "Data Column 5" = B
   and "Data Column 6" = 123
   and "Data Column 7" = 456
   and "Data Column 8" = GH

Column Name       Datatype/Length
============    ====================
ID        IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
Data Column 1   CHAR Length =  (2)
Data Column 2   CHAR Length =  (2)
Data Column 3   CHAR Length =  (2)
Data Column 4   CHAR Length =  (1)
Data Column 5   CHAR Length =  (1)
Data Column 6   CHAR Length =  (3)
Data Column 7   CHAR Length =  (3)
Data Column 8   CHAR Length =  (2)
Data Column 9   CHAR Length =  (8)
Audit Column 1  CHAR Length =  (1)
Audit Column 2  DATETIME
Audit Column 3  VARCHAR Length =  (20)
Audit Column 4  DATETIME
```

Could the experts advise on what columns should be indexed and how? Any thoughts on whether the SELECT query will take a few seconds or minutes? Any other advise around table setup or any other setup? All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: an option would be to hash the columns to a number  (in a computed column), index the computed column (4/8bytes int/bigint) and perform searches with the hashed value of the searched terms +  per column (for any possible duplicate hash values) --> index seek + lookup (clkey or rid)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a non-clustered covering index
that satisfy all requested columns in a query without doing a further lookup into the clustered index.

Below the script:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Table_Columns

ON dbo.Table ([Data Column 1] ASC, [Data Column 2] ASC, [Data Column 3] ASC, [Data Column 4] ASC, [Data Column 5] ASC, [Data Column 6] ASC, [Data Column 7] ASC, [Data Column 8] ASC)

INCLUDE ([Data Column 9])
 — WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

The execution time in my opinion will be a few milliseconds.

For production if you have a enterprise edition I reccomend adding `WITH(ONLINE = ON)` option, so you don't have blocks.

Click [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) for good article explaining the covering indexes.

Answer (score 0):

A composite index on `{"Data Column 1", "Data Column 2", "Data Column 3", "Data Column 4", "Data Column 5", "Data Column 6", "Data Column 7", "Data Column 8"}` should let this query find the row via a simple index seek.

Assuming no other surprises, I would expect millisecond-level performance.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a non-clustered index on "Data Column 1" ... "Data Column 8" will effectively repeat all the 400M rows with most of the table data, a better solution will be to remove clustered PK on ID if any, and create a clustered primary key on those 8 columns, as from your description we see that they are unique and ID is not used in any way, or just a clustered index on those columns if they are not unique. This also assumes you don't create non-clustered index on ID as that will again repeat all the table data. You can also add `WITH(NOLOCK)` in the query to not spend unnecessary resources and time on locks. Execution time will be millisecond level.